# Prove for a ring of 2x2 matrices, $M_2(Z)$ there is an element A $\in$ $M_2(Z)$ such that $A^n$ $\neq$ $A$ for every $n> 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove for a ring of 2x2 matrices, $M_2(Z)$ there is an element A $\in$ $M_2(Z)$ such that $A^n$ $\neq$ $A$ for every $n> 1$

I interpreted this question as showing that $A^2$ was not equal to $A$, however, my professor said I misinterpreted the question

Comment: you are also asked to show that $A^3, A^4,$ etc. aren't $A$; is $Z$ the set of integers?

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect because $A^2\neq A$ does *not* imply that $A^n \neq A$ for every $n>1$. As a counterexample, take $A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and prove that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]^n=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Another possibility is: take $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.